# Hello. I am working on app using Xcode. The active indicator in WKWebView is keep spining and not stop or disappear after loading content

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate  {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
   @IBOutlet weak var activeIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(myRequest)
       
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        activeIndicator.startAnimating()

    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation:   WKNavigationDelegate!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activeIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.activeIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.activeIndicator.isHidden = true
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activeIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(myRequest)
        self.webView.addSubview(self.activeIndicator)
        self.activeIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.activeIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
       
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activeIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        activeIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try below code.. set activity indicator properties in view did load .. updated code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate  {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
   @IBOutlet weak var activeIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.activeIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(myRequest)
       
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        activeIndicator.startAnimating()

    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation:   WKNavigationDelegate!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activeIndicator.stopAnimating()
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still spinning and not hiding